# How can I improve the display of my png files?

Tags: libgdx, sprites, image, transparency

I develop a [mini Android game available from my github](https://github.com/montao/gamex) (also the release apk file). The game is for kids and you are supposed to catch falling object and get points for that. Now I just created png files for the sprites and added alpha channel in gimp. It looks better, before alpha channel:

[image]

After:

[image]

But I'm not 100 % satisfied with the rough edges of the sprites. Am I correct that if I do the alpha channel more exact then the sprites will look even better (without the edges) or is there some other mistake that I make with the sprites?

Edit: With new background image, it looks like this.

[image]

Edit 2: I used jamie the monkey now of BSD license which renders better. It seems to be more exact work in GIMP that is needed.

[image]

Edit 3. Now I am satisfied. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a sprite problem, but without seeing the relevant code &/or the sprite assets, there's no way to tell. Related to that, if you want the code examined, you need to post it as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Finally, I hope you actually have the necessary license / authority to use Disney's IP - if not, change them.

Comment: Looks to me you left  in some opaque pixels in there. You simply have to remove them in gimp. Where is the source of the of transparent elsa png?

Comment: You forgot to remove the drop shadow from the images. Run the eraser around the edges to clean up the unwanted pixels.

Comment: @Pikalek It is for educational purposes. I'm pulling the sprites back because of the IP and put in FOSS sprites for demonstration purposes since the purpose of this project was learning the Android build environment and demonstrating small 2D sprites for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you Add the alpha channel, how did you remove the background? If there are still visible bits along the edge, you can use the Eraser tool to go over the edges, or the selection tool to select an area covering the edges and press [Delete] to remove the selected portion.

Remember, this works differently with images with an alpha channel or without; deleting without an alpha channel can only set the pixels to the background color. so even if you did this before adding alpha, you'd have to do it again.

---

Your image is here: [(github link)](https://github.com/montao/gamex/blob/633fca49665552543312931cf4dc38f9be62f881/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/hero.png). You can definitely see the shadow pixels that weren't removed (I guess when you used the magic wand to remove the White background?) -- you'll have to erase that part in Gimp.

Comment: Best way to remove pixels is to add a new layer and make it black. Place it at the bottom and some missed pixels should show up. Checker board background usually blends pixels which makes you easily miss them as well.